# Regex Expression to match currency numeric range

Tags: java, regex

How do you write a regular expression that matches currency numeric range from `-214748.00` or `-214748` to `214748.00`?

I tried this but not working.

```
^[-]?[0-9]{1,214748 }(?:\\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

Comment: I have to ask, if you have something numeric, why would you be using a regex?

Comment: My requirement is to limit numbers, if it exceeds limit then I need to throw an exception

Comment: This is most definitely NOT a job for regex.  Would you hammer a nail with a screwdriver? There is no easy way to write a regex to validate that a number is in a range unless the range limits are powers of 10 (i.e. -100000 <= x <= 100000)

Comment: I know. Its more easy with java than regex .But my requirement is creating regex if datatype is currency.

Comment: Then that is a bug/defect in the requirements.  It does no good to take bad requirements and implement them in code.

Comment: this is the scenario I need to implement it through Regex , why the hell people are disliking my question??

Comment: Because you are asking to do something that no competent programmer would agree to do.

Comment: If a layman asks you what is `2 + 2`, will you go on to write a script in `Perl` to calculate the value and give him the code? Or you would just explain him in layman language? On the other hand, if a programmer student asks you, then giving him a code is the option. So, context matters. It isn't that if you have something, so you can use it anywhere.

Comment: Thats not in my hand. whatever I get from them I am looking some work around to see If I will be able to implement or not.....

Comment: And if it's a homework, then better ask your teacher to give you a regex answer. And once he gives you the answer, ask him to modify the regex for range - `[1234, 325121234]` and see how much time he takes.

Comment: its not a homework. Like I said earlier, it is requirement from my current job. I am not posting questions for timepass, I am posting questions to get help from you

Comment: @Rani. Trust us. We're helping you by avoiding you to use regex. I can   come up with a regex but that would not be worth of time, neither mine, nor yours. Because if the range changes, you will have nightmares changing the regex.

Comment: understood.But what we are doing is creating this regex on upload of file and saving it in database. so that other system can use this regex to validate for that attribute, we are integrating  2  different projects.

Comment: Using regex for this kind of validation is shot in the foot. To ease a pain you can try using http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Comment: please add your comment as answer, I will accept it. Yo made my day:)

Comment: @Rani Sorry but that would be bad answer... If you really want to make your life harder you are free to do it but that is your choice. I don't want to encourage others to use this approach so I will leave it as comment.

Comment: @Pshemo: ok no problem.

Comment: @Rani. I've added a regex with an explanation in my answer. If only you like it.

Comment: Note about your example: in RegEx `{}` is a Quantifier so `[0-9]{1,214748}` is accepting a number between 1 and 214748 **digits** long !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working regex that does what you're asking for:

```
^-?((([0-9]{1,5}|1[0-9]{5}|2(0[0-9]{4}|1([0-3][0-9]{3}|4([0-6][0-9]{2}|7([0-3][0-9]|4[0-7])))))([.][0-9]{2})?)|214748([.]00)?)$
```

This relies heavily on the following sub-regex, which matches the range from 0 to 214747:

```
([0-9]{1,5}|1[0-9]{5}|2(0[0-9]{4}|1([0-3][0-9]{3}|4([0-6][0-9]{2}|7([0-3][0-9]|4[0-7])))))
```

Why from 0 to 214747 and not 0 to 214748? Because doing it this way it's easier to avoid matching values from 214748.01 to 214748.99 (+/-). Breaking down the regex, we get:

```
^ # match start of line
 -? # optional minus sign
  ( # match one of the following groups, this one:
   (
    ([0-9]{1,5}|1[0-9]{5}|2(0[0-9]{4}|1([0-3][0-9]{3}|4([0-6][0-9]{2}|7([0-3][0-9]|4[0-7])))))
    # the sub-regex above matches the range from 0 to 214747
    ([.][0-9]{2})? # this matches the optional two decimals
   ) 

   | # or this one:
   214748([.]00)? # 214748, with optional zeroes
  ) 
$ # match end of line
```

And there you have it, an overly complicated regex that's a nightmare to look at, let alone maintain. If you need to change the range, it will require a lot of work.

I hope this monstrosity discourages the use regex for this task. Do as everyone else says and process it using the appropriate tools. If regex is *required*, tell them it's a horrible idea and ask them to fix the requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Nonono. You are using the wrong tool for the job. Regex is just a text processing tool. It is bad at interpreting the meaning of text. When it comes to identifying the semantics of the text you need to process, that is where regex is not good.

You should use simple language tool and operators for this job. Apart from that, if you dealing with currencies, avoid using `double` or `float`. They don't have enough precision to represent all the floating point numbers accurately. Use a `BigDecimal` instead.

---

**Warning:** Please, don't ever use this for such issues:
**Note:** This doesn't handle floating point numbers.

Since you are insisting so much, I've come up with following regex which works for some input I've tested. I guess it would work fine for any integral values within the given range:

```
"-?(\\d{1,5}|1\\d{5}|2(?:0\\d{4}|1(?:[0-3]\\d{3}|4(?:[0-6]\\d{2}|7(?:[0-3]\\d|4[0-8])))))"
```

`-?` means optional `-` for negative number.

**Demo Code:**

```
String str = "-?(\\d{1,5}|1\\d{5}|2(?:0\\d{4}|1(?:[0-3]\\d{3}|4(?:[0-6]\\d{2}|7(?:[0-3]\\d|4[0-8])))))";

System.out.println("214748".matches(str));  // true
System.out.println("214746".matches(str));  // true
System.out.println("2148".matches(str));    // true
System.out.println("-21448".matches(str));  // true
System.out.println("-214747".matches(str)); // true
System.out.println("214749".matches(str));  // false
```

The regex uses the following facts. For range `[-214748, 214748]`:

- Any 5 or less digit numbers are valid - `\\d{1,5}`
- Any 6 digit number starting with `1` are valid - `1\\d{5}`
- For a number starting with `2`:

  - Further 5 digit numbers starting with `0` are valid - `20\\d{4}`
  - If number next to `2` is `1`

    1. Any further 4 digit numbers starting with `[0-3]` are valid - `21[0-3]\\d{3}`
    2. For any further 4 digit number starting with `4`:

       - numbers starting with `[0-6]` are valid - `214[0-6]\d{2}`
       - If digit after `4` is `7`, then

         1. Any further numbers starting with `[0-3]` are valid - `2147[0-3]\\d`
         2. If digit after `7` is `4`, then range `[0-8]` after `4` is valid - `21474[0-8]`

Comment: @Downvoter Care to comment.

Comment: @NullUserException. I didn't answered to provide a solution. I have just added why regex shouldn't be used, and gave an idea what should be used. I would expect OP to at least do this job with operators.

Comment: Fair enough. But I downvoted the answer before the ninja edit